# C# Class library within Class Library

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, class, reference

I have a C# solution in VS2010 that contains three projects. This solution has a client project (A) and a server project (B) which both build into applications. The third project (C) is where my classes that are common to both projects go (like a utility library) and this is built into a class library, which I reference in both the client and the server.

Now I want to reference a 3rd party library in my common library (C). I reference the dll and everything seems fine, I am able to use it within that project. However, when I try to use the class I created (that makes reference to the dll) in either the client or server, I get a FileNotFoundException (In regards to the 3rd party library).

I also tried to reference the 3rd party library in my client and server project as well as in the common code project, but the error is still occurring.

I also saw this question here, [.NET Multiple Class Library in One Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056892/net-multiple-class-library-in-one-library), which suggests to me that you can reference a class within a class, so how would I go about doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to copy the 3rd-party DLL, *and all of its dependencies*, to the folders containing your executables.

You can do that by setting `Copy Local` to true in the properties of the references.

Comment: Cheers! The dependencies (of the 3rd party dll) weren't being copied. Although it seems my references have copy local set to true by default. I only had to copy the missing dependency manually.