# Link static library to a dynamic library

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019, static-libraries, dynamic-library

I have a Visual Studio 2019 DLL project, and I want to link a library statically against it. When I use symbols from the static library in the dll, it builds correctly. However, when I link my dynamic library project to an executable application, the application gives an unresolved external symbol error. Do I have to link the static library against the application as well?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Statically linking a DLL in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490685/statically-linking-a-dll-in-windows)

Answer (score 0):

A `DLL` is a binary, similar to an `EXE` file, so when you link it against your static library, all dependencies have to be satisfied. An `EXE` file linking against this dynamic library doesn't know about any of it's internals like the symbols of some static library, and consequently there should not be any unresolved symbols because of the static library.

The only way you can get this, is if you link the `EXE` also against the static library and use some symbols from it, but this independent of the `DLL`.

So no, unless you are using something from the static library in your `EXE` file, then you don't need to link against it.