# Why can't you combine a DLL with an EXE, as if it had been statically linked?

Tags: linker, shared-libraries, executable, static-libraries

Why isn't it possible* to "re-link" a native shared library (DLL) into an executable file, as if they had been statically linked? Is the DLL missing any required information?

<sup>*Note: Or is it actually posible? If it is, please let me know, but through searches I've come to the conclustion that it's not possible.</sup>

Comment: Check DLL to lib, in an answer for this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/424032/how-to-link-a-dll-statically

Comment: It's not a generally solvable problem, because the EXE may rely on dynamic loading, obtaining function addresses via the DLL's HMODULE and a function name, etc.

Comment: @Pablo: Interesting, I'll look at it, thanks.
@Damien_The_Unbeliever: For the sake of this question, please assume the exe doesn't explicitly depend on this fact to be true. :)

Answer (score 1):

It isn't directly possible.

When an EXE loads a DLL (via `LoadLibrary`) there's a *lot* of work done by the DLL loader to patch adresses. You can't *just* combine a DLL *as is* with an exe, because its adresses are *wrong* if it's not *dynamically* loaded.

On the other hand, a LIB is statically linked: no loading involved, no adress fixing, everything works without further job when you launch the program.

What is possible to do is to convert a DLL and EXE back to OBJ and link them together statically.

Comment: @Heandel: Did you by any chance happen to read my reply comment to @Damien?

Comment: @Heandel: Yeah, I know what you mean by everything being dynamic, but isn't it a little different if you're not explicitly calling `LoadLibrary`? In that case, the executable should be (relatively) easily modifiable to allow the import thunks to directly call an embedded library, no?

Comment: @Heandel: Also, how do you convert a DLL or EXE back to OBJ? Isn't it missing some information?

Comment: @Heandel: Hm... when I try doing that with NDISASM/NASM, I get: `error: Win32 COFF does not correctly support relative references to absolute addresses`... are you sure that's possible?