# Is it possible to create a DLL which contains another DLL?

Tags: c#, dll, netmodules

I am working on a project. The task is to create a DLL Project. In that project, I am having an existing DLL with set of methods. With the use of existing DLL I can call some methods and create some methods in the new DLL.

Is that Possible in C#? What are the possibilities and methods to create such a project?

Comment: like a DLLception...?

Comment: Do you want to actually create methods at runtime, or just call methods on an existing DLL?  You can certainly embed another DLL as a resource and extract and load it at runtime if that's what you need.  As it stands though, this question is a little unclear.  Be careful it doesn't end up too broad if you clarify anything though...

Comment: It definitelly is possible. Please, provide more information - what IDE are you using? Do you want the `Existing DLL` to be "hidden" inside your resulting .dll, or are you fine with it being part of the project output?

Comment: Yes. You can use **ILMerge** tool to merge existing DLLs into one file. More info http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9364/Merging-NET-assemblies-using-ILMerge.

Comment: The IDE is Visual studio 2008. The DLL Might be hidden inside our resulting dll. I am using C# code.

Comment: James. My Question is simple. I need to create a DLL with an existing DLL. The Existing DLL functionalities might be used in the New DLL. The Existing DLL behind the Original One..

Comment: If the existing DLL is a thrid party one, be carefull about its licence. Not so much DLL creators like to see it hidden in others libraries.

Comment: IronSlug I have the license of that dude

Answer (score 6):

If you want to hide that DLL in the contents of your own DLL, you can simply put it into resources. From the standpoint of *resources*, a DLL is just a file like any other and you can simply add it to [program resources](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k989cfy%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) and simply [drop the file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10412442/1149736) where you need it.

However this will prohibit you from using *implicit linking* and you will have to [*link the DLL explicitly*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/784bt7z7.aspx). MSDN already offers [a quite reasonable tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468.aspx#pinvoke_callingdllexport) already and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/25y1ya39.aspx).

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

public class Asmload0
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // Use the file name to load the assembly into the current 
        // application domain.
        Assembly a = Assembly.Load("example");
        // Get the type to use.
        Type myType = a.GetType("Example");
        // Get the method to call.
        MethodInfo myMethod = myType.GetMethod("MethodA");
        // Create an instance. 
        object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(myType);
        // Execute the method.
        myMethod.Invoke(obj, null);
    }
}
```

---

If you want to create your own DLL that just uses *the old one* you may just [*Add Reference*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky.aspx). Then you can set up ["Use Copy Local"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee817675.aspx), but you will have to distribute two files:

[image: Copy Local Visual Studio Screenshot]

---

And if you want to make "*static link*" simply by compiler/linker (build in to visual studio) you need to use a statically linked library (LIB) and not a dynamically linkws library (DLL)...

Or you can try reading "[*How to link a .DLL statically?*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/424049/1149736)" which seems to provide some guidance (proprietary software) on how to do this.

Comment: Main Problem is I need to create a DLL Project with the Existing one. I want to use the existing one in my project by using reference. Can You tell me how to create a DLL With Migrating the Existing DLL in C#.??

Comment: Boss I dont have the "Old DLL project". I only Have a DLL. I am Creating a new DLL Project. To enhance something and Create a New DLL with existing features of the old DLL.

Comment: thank u so much .... But I already refer the page. I done the following methods by creating a net module. But It shows some errors. That's Why I have the doubt about my path is correct or not.